# node.js create / modify Exif inside the JPEG

Tags: javascript, node.js, exif

Is there a native Javascript module that allows creating / modifying EXIF and IPTC sections inside the JPEG file ?

Note: I already have the Exif data of the image that I am receiving from iPhone along with the image. Since he image does not include all the metadata in itself, I want to combine it and save it on my server.

I came across a one module in my search but that seems abandoned and it never implemented writing of EXIF.

https://github.com/logicalparadox/exifdata

Does anyone know of a pure Javascript module that I can use ?

I did find a C library "libexif" that can do the job. I have not tested it yet. I'm still trying to stay with Javascript.

[Write exif data to jpg using libexif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685839/write-exif-data-to-jpg-using-libexif)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[PiexifJS](https://github.com/hMatoba/piexifjs) did the job for me. Runs on the browser and on node. No external dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately this library does not support IPTC data.